# Parse a google maps xml with xPath + Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-maps, xpath

I am a bit confused on how to go about developing an application, using Google maps javascript API + the 'Places' library.

What I want to have:

an html page with 2 divs:

a. **left div**: contains the google map + results/markers based on a given location ( I have that already)

b. **right div**: contains a list of the results with drop-down menus to filter the results on the map, on the left div.

So my questions are:

a. The response is already loaded in an object for the map on the left div, as in this example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search

Do I need to load it again - in order to get this information in XML and parse it in the right div?

My xml request is for example:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=34.680617,33.043263&radius=500&types=store&key=AIzaSyDQ9fpqxWt0F5EsztFt-HSjcSQruJSGeik

Where would I insert this (in the above example code) in order to get the xml response and parse the file/node information in text format on the right div?

b. In the callback function there is a loop that goes through the results:

```
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Could I use that same loop in order to parse the xml nodes without having to load the xml file again?
If yes, the google developers site does not have an example of how to do that. It only lists a few xPath expressions:

developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/index#ParsingXML

but it does not provide a full complete example from scratch.
i.e. how to use xPath to parse the xml file with javascript

c. if we need to have 2 separate responses (the google maps api + the web service), how will these 2 communicate between them then?

Not sure if I got it all wrong here...

thanks,
k.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to use the same loop to parse the xml you could try something like:

```
function callback(results, status)
{
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        {
            // Untested but use JQuery and try this:
            var name = $(results[i]).find('name').text();
            var location = $(results[i]).find('location');
            var lat = $(location).find('lat').text();
            var lng = $(location).find('long').text();
            var obj =
            {
                name: name,
                lat : lat,
                lng: lng
            };    
            createMarker(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

I would keep track of the markers your creating in an array or something to manage them on the map.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ioanburger but it doesn't work. No markers even show up on the map. Also I added ".text" to the line find('location') - but it still doesn't work.
Also, I am not an expert in JS - (and no experiencein JQuery), how would I keep track of the markers in an array?

Comment: Just create a global or namespace variable and just after you created them add them to that array.  As for them not showing up on the map make sure the values are coming out of the xml properly.  Ill do a js fiddle to later to show you

Comment: My problem basically is that there is not a single example for what Documentation describes here...how can we see it in action then??

developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/index#ParsingXML